# How to I modify arrays inside of a map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am working with a map with strings as keys and arrays as values.  I would like to adjust the map to be the original strings and change the arrays to the average values.

The original map is:

```
val appRatings = mapOf(
            "Calendar Pro" to arrayOf(1, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4),
            "The Messenger" to arrayOf(5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2),
            "Socialise" to arrayOf(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2)
    )
```

What I have tried to do is:

```
val averageRatings = appRatings.forEach{ (k,v) -> v.reduce { acc, i -> acc + 1 }/v.size}
```

However this returns a Unit instead of a map in Kotlin.  What am I doing wrong?  I am working through a lambda assignment and they want us to use foreach and reduce to get the answer.

Comment: because `forEach` doesn't return anything (returns Unit) it just iterates over iterable object (array in your case). In your loop you probably want add result of your calculation into `averageRatings`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `forEach` and `reduce`, but it's overkill, because you can just use `mapValues` and take the average:

```
val appRatings = mapOf(
    "Calendar Pro" to arrayOf(1, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4),
    "The Messenger" to arrayOf(5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2),
    "Socialise" to arrayOf(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2)
)

val averages = appRatings.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.average() }

println(averages)
```

Output:

```
{Calendar Pro=3.375, The Messenger=3.0, Socialise=2.0}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped out the most.  Can you give an example of using forEach?  When I use it, it changes the output to Unit and not Map.

As for the instructions, I have to use reduce to get the averages, so I was able to adjust the code to: val averageRatings = appRatings.mapValues { (_, v) -> v.reduce{acc, i -> acc+i}/v.size }.  However the averages are now Int.  In the future I'll use your method.

Comment: Can you link to the exercise? It really seems like a bad example for learning `forEach`, since it's so much clearer to use `mapValues` in this case. You *could* do it by making a mutable map and copying in the averages, but it's definitely an inferior solution. `val averageMap = mutableMapOf<String, Double>(); appRatings.forEach { (k, v) -> averageMap[k] = v.average() }`.

Comment: Here is the prompt: "First, create a map called averageRatings which will contain a mapping of app names to average ratings. Use forEach to iterate through the appRatings map, then use reduce to calculate the average rating and store this rating in the averageRatings map."

Comment: I agree, the proposed solutions are much slicker.  Even with that prompt, I don't think I could have figured that out on my own.  I had already spend about 1.5 hours trying to solve it before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `mapValues` function:

```
val appRatings = mapOf(
        "Calendar Pro" to arrayOf(1, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4),
        "The Messenger" to arrayOf(5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2),
        "Socialise" to arrayOf(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2)
    )

    val ratingsAverage = appRatings.mapValues { it.value.average() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got some answers (including literally from JetBrains?? nice) but just to clear up the `forEach` thing:

`forEach` is a "do something with each item" function that returns nothing (well, `Unit`) - it's terminal, the last thing you can do in a chain, because it doesn't return a value to do anything else with. It's basically a `for` loop, and it's about side effects, not transforming the collection that was passed in and producing different data.

`onEach` is similar, except it returns the original item - so you call `onEach` on a collection, you get the same collection as a result. So this one isn't terminal, and you can pop it in a function chain to do something with the current set of values, without altering them.

`map` is your standard "transform items into other items" function - if you want to put a collection in and get a different collection out (like transforming arrays of Ints into single Int averages) then you want `map`. (The name comes from mapping values onto other values, translating them - which is why you always get the same number of items out as you put in)